# Visual Basic 2010 Login view asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've recently created an asp.net application with a membership login and registeration using the generic template in Visual Studios 2010.  Below is how the template looks like within Visual Studios:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/79954191@N05/7345407648/

Then once I load the application it re-directs me to the login screen (as it should) but the problem is it's missing all the template / css elements.  Below is a picture when loaded:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/79954191@N05/7160199089/

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Have you looked to make sure that the CSS files are being included properly, and are accessible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check web.config for permissions on the css folder.

You must use location for give permissions to no-authenticated users

```
<location path="pathToCssFolder">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Check this link : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871

Comment: I tried that, I think it might have something to do with the ASP.NET Configurations.  I'm trying to deny all anonymous users access on the root folder.  Am I doing that correctly?

Comment: Ok I think I got it.  In ASP.Configurations I denied access to all anonymous users (which is what I wanted) this forces the application to take you to the login page.  To allow all users to see the style/css, you have to create a new web.config file within your styles folder and make sure it looks like this:

          <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
          </authorization>


This should all everyone to see the styles and site.css files. Thank you rolivares for your help! and fast response!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the stylesheets are pointing in the right directory.
Open your Site.Master file and make sure the link to the file is as follows:
href="~/path/to/folder/yourcss.css"
The tilde sign (~) means root of the project.

Comment: All paths look correct to me.  It might be something with the ASP.NET Configuration, when I deny anonymous users access it messes up the login page.  When I take off the deny role it starts to work fine.